# Why did EnterpriseLibrary Cryptographer zero-out the key and randomly overwrite plain text after transforming?

Tags: c#, encryption, enterprise-library

I'm looking at MS EnterpriseLibrary source code because I have some old hashed and encrypted strings I'm going to have to support (and re-encrypt in the case of encryption) in a new application. I see that when it finishes encrypting or decrypting, it zeros-out the encryption key `byte[]` and in the case of encryption, it replaces the plain text `byte[]` with random bytes. See below:

```
using (ICryptoTransform transform = this.algorithm.CreateDecryptor())
{
    output = Transform(transform, data);
}

CryptographyUtility.ZeroOutBytes(this.algorithm.Key);
```

Further down the stack:

```
byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertextBase64);
byte[] decryptedBytes = DecryptSymmetric(symmetricInstance, cipherTextBytes);
string decryptedString = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedBytes);
CryptographyUtility.GetRandomBytes(decryptedBytes);
```

I'm assuming the goal is not to leave sensitive data sitting in memory, but I'm left wondering why use zeros for the key and cryptographically strong random bytes for the plain text as opposed to using the same method for both?

It also appends the IV to the beginning of the encrypted text. Does that not defeat the purpose of the IV? I thought the IV was meant to be kept as secret as the key. Otherwise doesn't that give a hint about the encryption?

Comment: The IV must be unpredictable (read: random). An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before if the same IV is being used. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption. The key is the only thing that needs to be secret. See: Kerckhoffs's principle

Comment: My guess is that they had no idea what they where doing, because `this.algorithm.Key` is a copy of the key that is stored inside of `this.algorithm`. This code isn't cleaning up anything. Proof of concept: http://ideone.com/nL4sIJ (note the line `rijAlg.Key[2] = 0;` which should change the key but the encryption still produces a valid ciphertext)

Comment: I noticed that too since my OP. `decryptedBytes` does get overwritten though.